# Always 'error writing output file' in openssl

Tags: linux, openssl

I created a 5 MiB random file using `openssl` with `head`:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:1o0SxTnYvbtjFtKLiuv3ccPebLOJiUU -nosalt < /dev/zero | head -c 5M > /mnt/pny1/file1
```

It created a file of the correct size, but also gave an error message:

```
error writing output file
```

I tried it with `dd` and got the same result:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:1o0SxTnYvbtjFtKLiuv3ccPebLOJiUU -nosalt < /dev/zero | dd of=/mnt/pny1/file2 bs=1M count=5 iflag=fullblock
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
error writing output file
5242880 bytes (5.2 MB) copied, 0.0194212 s, 270 MB/s
```

I then tried overwriting a loop device using `openssl` with `cat`:

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:1o0SxTnYvbtjFtKLiuv3ccPebLOJiUU -nosalt < /dev/zero | cat > /dev/loop0
cat: write error: No space left on device
error writing output file
```

Always `error writing output file`.

Why is this error occurring and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's openssls incorrect handling of `SIGPIPE`. `head` and also `dd` will close the pipe when they have recieved their 5 MB. This produces an `EPIPE` error on the `write()` system call when the openssl process tries to write to the pipe:

> ```
> EPIPE    fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed. When this
>          happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.
> ```

openssl then died due to a signal rather than exiting normally. You can check that in your example using:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:password -nosalt < /dev/zero | head -c 5M >file
error writing output file
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
1 0
```

The `$PIPESTATUS` array contains the exit values of the processes within the pipes. You see the openssl process exited with exit code 1.

---

However, to overcome that error, use `head` or `dd` before openssl in the pipe:

```
$ head -c 5M /dev/zero | openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:password -nosalt >file
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 0
```

Comment: Does `cat` also close the pipe when it reaches uses up all the space on the block device?

Comment: I meant to say: does `cat` also close the pipe when it's finished overwriting all of the space on the block device?

Comment: @EmmaV When `cat` is no longer able to write to the device it stops, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If the data for decrypting is too little, then you can run into this problem.
I used a GNU parallel utility. Had this problem (error writing output file). Fixed it with adding min size for blocks using --blocksize.
Also, openssl is kind of a weirdo, it returns this error on any problem I encountered (wrong password for decrypting, wrong data for decrypting). So be aware.

Answer (score 0):

If other answers don't fix your problem, **try padding the message** to a longer length.

Use the length of the key, or a multiple of that.

Nothing else answered the above question so I decided to check the message I was encoding. It was very short. I padded it with spaces, up to the length of the key, and that fixed it.